# react native navigation cannot display light image in stack navigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have a react native stack navigator screen which will display an image.

If found out if the image is dark background (something like this https://tctechcrunch2011.files.wordpress.com/2015/09/react-native.png?w=738) it will display just fine, while if it's a regular image, it won't display (https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRf148EuQqC90pqKVJvjraTejon1-A5OKkMuwsnBfxRDlWq1foe) . I don't know how to trouble shoot it. If there's any tips or suggestions of how to get it work. i really appreciate.

My example code for the Stack Navigator view looks like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  // Notice these imports:
  TextInput,
  Image,
  Dimensions,
  TouchableOpacity

} from 'react-native';
const screenHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height;
const screenWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;

export default class AboutScreen extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => ({
    title: navigation.state.params.recipe.label,
  });
  render() {
    const { goBack } = this.props.navigation;
    const imgUrl = this.props.navigation.state.params.recipe.image;
    console.log("imgUrl is >>>", imgUrl);
    console.log("this.props.navigation is >>>", this.props.navigation);
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.picture}>
          <Image
              style={{width: 200, height: 200}}
              source={{uri: imgUrl}}
            /> 
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1
  },
  picture: {
    margin: 10,
    height: screenWidth *0.8,
    paddingLeft: 10,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    shadowColor: "#000000",
    shadowOpacity: 0.8,
    shadowRadius: 2,
    shadowOffset: {
      height: 1,
      width: 0
    }
  },

});
```

Comment: try adding `resizeMode="stretch"` in `Image` props.

Comment: tried that and still no luck

Answer (score 0):

Your image is may not loaded from the uri. You can check a possible error on loading with `onError`.

```
<Image
    style={{width: 200, height: 200}}
    source={{uri: imgUrl}}
    onError={e=>console.log(e)}
/>
```

Have you tried to use the same image as static resource with require from your assets folder?

```
<Image
    style={{width: 200, height: 200}}
    source={require("../path/to/your/image.jpg")}
    onError={e=>console.log(e)}
/>
```